# When should I use record syntax for data declarations in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Record syntax seems extremely convenient compared to having to write your own accessor functions. I've never seen anyone give any guidelines as to when it's best to use record syntax over normal data declaration syntax, so I'll just ask here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use record syntax in two situations:

1. The type has many fields
2. The type declaration gives no clue about its intended layout

For instance a Point type can be simply declared as:

```
data Point = Point Int Int deriving (Show)
```

It is obvious that the first Int denotes the *x* coordinate and the second stands for *y*. But the case with the following type declaration is different (taken from [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)):

```
data Person = Person String String Int Float String String deriving (Show)
```

The intended type layout is: first name, last name, age, height, phone number, and favorite ice-cream flavor. But this is not evident in the above declaration. Record syntax comes handy here:

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , lastName :: String  
                     , age :: Int  
                     , height :: Float  
                     , phoneNumber :: String  
                     , flavor :: String  
                     } deriving (Show)
```

The record syntax made the code more readable, and saved a great deal of typing by automatically defining all the accessor functions for us!

Comment: You also have an interesting use of record syntax in the `State` monad, where `runState` is used as a bit of syntactic cleverness.

Comment: You could leverage the typesystem and use type aliasing like

`type FirstName = String
type LastName = String
type Age = Int
type Height = Float
type PhoneNumber = String
type Flavor = String

data Person = Person FirstName LastName Age Height PhoneNumber Flavor deriving (show)
`

Therefore your argument is invalid.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to complex multi-fielded data, `newtype`s are often defined with record syntax. In either of these cases, there aren't really any downsides to using record syntax, but in the case of sum types, record accessors usually don't make sense. For example:

```
data Either a b = Left { getLeft :: a } | Right { getRight :: b }
```

is valid, but the accessor functions are *partial* – it is an error to write `getLeft (Right "banana")`. For that reason, such accessors are generally speaking discouraged; something like `getLeft :: Either a b -> Maybe a` would be more common, and that would have to be defined manually. However, note that accessors can share names:

```
data Item = Food { description :: String, tastiness :: Integer }
    | Wand { description :: String, magic :: Integer }
```

Now `description` is total, although `tastiness` and `magic` both still aren't.